# Logging output from script running in bash appears as one line

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I wrote a sample code for a logging script. But if i run it from bash, all log entries appear one the same line. However, if I run it from IDLE it will print a properly formatted multiline output. Why is it doing this? And how can I patch it? This is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import logging

formatter=logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s \n %(levelname)s %(message)s')
file_handler=logging.FileHandler(path/to/the/file)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

e = '0123'

def loggegfv(n,c):
    for i in e:
        logger.info("{} Ti avrò mai creato? {}".format(n,c))
        logger.error("Come me {}".format(i))


loggegfv("Checcazzo loggami","Forse funziona")
```

EDIT: For future readers, i solved this problem. The thing i didnt mention was that i was using WSL Ubuntu as a bash, and the newline encoding was different (obviously) than in Windows. So, when i opened the log file in bash, the file was displayed correctly, instead of Windows that displayed the single line output. Using a different text decoder (notepad++) solved the issue.

Comment: hi, I realize this is quite an old question but could you please take your 'Edit' part and self-answer your question? That way people having a similiar issue can easier spot your solution.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, I solved this problem. The thing I didn't mention was that I was using WSL Ubuntu as a bash, and the newline encoding was different (obviously) than in Windows (Unix-like WSL use LF where Windows use CR+LF). So, when I opened the log file in bash, the file was displayed correctly, instead of Windows that displayed the single line output. Using a different text decoder (notepad++) solved the issue.

UPDATE 06/2019:
Standard Windows Notepad app should now support both encoding.